# Incorrect IP address when using Ethernet library with Arduino Uno and WizNet 5500 ethernet module

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I'm trying to get an ethernet module with the W5500 chipset to connect to my network on an Arduino Uno, but whatever I do, I always get an incorrect IP address.

The module is connected as default SPI, with the CS pin on pin 10.

Initially I was using the wrong libraries (those meant for the ENC28J60), until Juraj pointed out to me that I [had the W5500 chipset](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/92678/how-to-connect-and-use-hanrun-hr961160c-ethernet-component?noredirect=1#comment213990_92678).

So I loaded the Ethernet WebServer example sketch in my Arduino IDE (1.8.13), changed the IP value, compiled it, and tried to run it. In my code, I set the IP to 192.168.123.225, but the serial monitor showed me IP 192.80.239.132 .

After some Googling I found a post called [Ethernet library not initializing IP correctly](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ethernet-library-not-initializing-ip-correctly/664466), as well as several other pages each stating that the Ethernet2 library should be used for the W5500 chipset instead of Ethernet.

I've tried installing the Ethernet2 library from within the Arduino IDE, with the exact same result. I loaded the example sketch of this library, same result. After downloading the library from [GitHub](https://codeload.github.com/adafruit/Ethernet2/zip/refs/heads/master) (as found on another page describing the same problem), I got some errors and commented out some sections as seen in my code below, but still with the same result.

In the commented code you can also see that I've added a check to see whether my module is actually recognized as a W5500, and it is...

So my question, while elaborate, is very simple: how can I set the IP correctly on a W5500 chipset module connected to an Arduino Uno?

Here is my code (I've left out the loop, obviously):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>

// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 123, 225);

// Initialize the Ethernet server library
// with the IP address and port you want to use
// (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup()
{
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
  {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Ethernet WebServer Example");

  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // Check for Ethernet hardware present
  /*
  if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware)
  {
    Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
    while (true)
    {
      delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetW5500)
    {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield is a W5500");
    }    
  }

  if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF)
  {
    Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
  }
  */

  // start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}
```

Comment: Is your network using DHCP? Perhaps the network is trying to assign the IP address "it wants" to your device. Is there a test sketch with the W5500 library that uses DHCP to connect to the network? Maybe this sketch could help to narrow down the issue... https://github.com/RoboCore/Ethernet_W5500/blob/master/examples/DhcpAddressPrinter/DhcpAddressPrinter.ino

Comment: try the WebClient example of the Ethernet library version 2.0.0+. it has enhanced diagnostics (don't comment it out)

Comment: @VE7JRO Yes, my network is using DHCP, but if the address was a DHCP address, it would be in the range 192.168.123.x . I'll give the sketch you mentioned a try to find out what IP I get when using DHCP, I'm curious to find out if DHCP does work.

Comment: @Juraj Thanks for the pointer, I'll give it a go and update accordingly. And no, I won't comment out the diagnostics ;)

Comment: @VE7JRO Well, I downloaded the Ethernet_W5500 library from your link, replaced all files under "Ethernet" with those files and tried the WebServer example client again after verifying in the source code that the W5500 was active, but unfortunately I still get the wrong IP address (192.80.239.132).

Comment: @Juraj I've checked and (prior to testing VE7JRO's answer) I had the 2.0.2 version of the Ethernet library. I loaded the WebClient example, but as it was, I never got a DHCP address (I changed the MAC address in the code to one which is allowed on my network). I gave up on DHCP and set a static IP (same as above), but just like the code VE7JRO pointed to, I ended up with the same erroneous IP address...

Comment: check the wiring

Comment: @Juraj The wiring is correct as far as I can tell. Vcc to 3.3V (from a separate supply), gnd combined with the Arduino, SCK to pin 13 of the Arduino, Mi (miso) to 12, Mo (mosi) to 11, SC (ss) to 10 (as stated in the code, the only variable pin). Int pin is not connected, Reset pin is not connected (these are never mentioned in the articles I found).

Comment: should the module be powered with 3.3 V? some Ethernet modules have a converter from 5 V to 3.3 V for the W5500, because some Arduinos can't provide enough current on the 3.3 V pin

Comment: @Juraj Yes, this particular module should be powered by 3.3V. Also, I'm not powering the module from the Arduino but from a separate (lab) power supply, and yes, both grounds (Arduino and lab power supply) are connected.

Comment: if `begin` hangs it is a problem with communication with the module

Comment: @Juraj Begin doesn't hang, the entire setup gets executed, and the final Serial.println prints an incorrect IP address.

Comment: I meant `begin` using DHCP. `begin` with static IP never fails but if it didn't work, reading the IP address back gives you a random value.

Comment: @Juraj I'm afraid I'm a bit confused now, I'm not using DHCP. Or are you telling me to begin by using DHCP as a test? Because I already tested using DHCP and I never get an IP address, whether or not the MAC address I assign is explicitly allowed in my network.

Comment: I am still at the WebClient example of the Ethernet library as a basic troubleshooting tool

Comment: @Juraj That's the sketch I was trying on March 29, but I never got a DHCP address. That's why I switched to using a static IP address. Any idea on how to figure out why the DHCP begin hangs?

Comment: W5500 works fine with IP ranges upto xxx.127.xxx.xxx But with the second octect 128 or higher, the IP becomes some random numbers ie gets corrupt . Unable to resolve the problem. For other IP ranges, there no issue

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue: a strange IP was shown. Also the LEDs of the Lan connection had a rather strange blinking: green went on for a second then off and then orange did the same. The solution for me: an external power supply with 7 V at the Vin. Apparently the Lan shield is drawing too much power for the usb power supply...

Also it is working with the standard ethernet library

Comment: something is wrong with your hardware if USB doesn't provide enough power for Uno with Ethernet shield